# Instance variable reset everytime component re-render in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I created one functional component and declared some variables in it.

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  let instanceVariable = null;

  const selectValue = (value) => {
    instanceVariable = value;
  }

  const proccessVariable = () => {
   // Use instanceVariable and do some task
  }

  return(
    <SelectionOption onChange={selectValue} />
  );
}
```

I observed that whenever parent component of `Foo` is re-rendered or sometime `Foo` itself re-renders `instanceVariable` set back to `null`. Instead of this I want to save `selectedValue` init and proccess it later on `proccessVariable()` method.

If I set `instanceVariable` as `state` it will work and there is no need of state to just hold the selected value.

I know `useEffect(()=>{}, [])` only run one time but how can I declare `instanceVariable` there and use it in other functions.

Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use a `ref` there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you declare a variable directly in your functional component, its value is reset everytime your component re-renders. You can make use of `useRef` to declare instance variables in functional component

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  let instanceVariable = useRef(null);

  const selectValue = (value) => {
    instanceVariable.current = value; // make sure to use instanceVariable.current
  }

  const proccessVariable = () => {
   // Use instanceVariable.current and do some task
  }

  return(
    <SelectionOption onChange={selectValue} />
  );
}
```

Comment: this was a life saver