# why does the count keep on repeating and or causing items with repeated keys to spawn in my react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a quick question. I'm pretty new to react, so this may seem like a rather repeated or simple question. however, I'm struggling to understand some concepts that React has to offer.

I have the code below inside my App.JSX file:

```
import viteLogo from './../public/vite.svg'
import './App.css'
import {useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
    let count = 4;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        numbers.push(<p key={"parNumber-" + i}>{i + 1}</p>);
    }

    function addEl() {
        // numbers.push(<p key={"parNumber-" + count}>{count + 1}</p>);
        setNumbers((numList) => {
            console.log('added on ' + count);
            count++;
            return [...numList, <p key={count - 1}>{count}</p>]
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                    <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo"/>
                </a>
                <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                    <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <button onClick={addEl}>add</button>
            <div className={"holderDiv"}>
                {numbers}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

All that I'm trying to do is to add new paragraphs into the div that I have, based on a *useState* variable. The problem that I'm facing is that the app does not let me just simply add to the array. on each button click, multiple paragraphs are added and the *count* variable is acting strangely.

I tried using the below indexing, but it does not update the view.

```
    function addEl() {
        // numbers.push(<p key={"parNumber-" + count}>{count + 1}</p>);
        numbers.push(<p key={"parNumber-" + count}>{count + 1}</p>);
        count++;
        console.log(numbers)
    }
```

so please, I appreciate any answers on this topic. I truly do.
any extra explanation over why this is even happening is also appreciated as well.

Thanks for your time and effort

quick edit:

I also tried to do it this way:

```
function addEl() {
        // numbers.push(<p key={"parNumber-" + count}>{count + 1}</p>);
        numbers.push(<p key={"parNumber-" + count}>{count + 1}</p>);
        count++;
        setNumbers(numbers);
    }
```

doesn't work. I have no idea what I'm doing :_(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instance variable reset everytime component re-render in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862672/instance-variable-reset-everytime-component-re-render-in-reactjs)

Comment: Move `let count = 4;` above `function App() {`

Comment: not really. I think my question is a little vague. All that I want is to update a list or a div based on a list of paragraphs I have. I want to be able to remove and add to them in real-time and have the display update. Is there any way to do that? @Konrad

Answer (score 0):

So far I understood, you want to show multiple dynamic html with some defaults to start with, you can do something like this

```
import viteLogo from './../public/vite.svg'
import './App.css'
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function App() {
    const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState<any[]>([]);

   // you need to use useEffect so that every time you click add button, state doesn't behave wierdly
    useEffect(() => {
        setNumbers(() =>
            Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, index) => {
                return <p key={`parNumber-${index}`}>{index + 1}</p>;
            }),
        );
    }, []);

    function addEl() {
        setNumbers(numList => {
            const toBeAddedIndex = numList.length;
            console.log('added on ' + toBeAddedIndex);
            return [...numList, <p key={`parNumber-${toBeAddedIndex}`}>{toBeAddedIndex + 1}</p>];
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                    <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo"/>
                </a>
                <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                    <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <button onClick={addEl}>add</button>
            <div className="holderDiv">{numbers}</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

[image: tested in local]